# pfctl in OpenBSD and FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, openbsd, pf

I've noticed that both FreeBSD and NetBSD have extra pfctl options:
**pfctl [-AdeghmNnOPqRrvz]**

But OpenBSD doesn't, it's missing around five of the extra options:
**pfctl [-deghnPqrvz]**

I would have thought that as pf is from OpenBSD that it would have these options too. Does anyone know why it doesn't, or how to get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "extra" options were deprecated by OpenBSD over 9 years ago and removed in `pfctl` revision 1.143 (Mar 23, 2010) with the following comments:

> remove -A, -O, -R and -T load
>   the partial loading of a ruleset (leaving ancors aside) is wrong and
>   conflicts with the general idea of how pf works. last not least it breaks
>   with the optimizer generating tables automagically.

You could conceivably graft the functionality back into a current copy of `pfctl`, but that'd be "fun"...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a shame, I thought the extra functionality was useful.